# Show Link If Views Basic UI is Editable

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I'm using Views Basic UI in Drupal 6 to allow users to edit a views header and title.  I would like to cut back on the number of view templates that I have, so that in the future if I need to edit, I would only have to make changes in one place.

To do that, I'd like the views template "views-view--page.tpl.php" to provide a link only if the view is editable as defined by  the Views Basic UI: Edit Settings module.  I'm just not sure what the code should look like. I think it'd be something along the lines of

```
<?php if (in_array('views_basic_ui'): ?>
<div class="page-edit"> ...
```

I don't know what to put in that if statement though, in order to say "only print this button if the view has been selected as editable in the views basic ui settings". I'm guessing somebody that reads/writes code better than me could figure it out pretty quick, but I'd appreciate any help I could get.

Thanks.

ps - it's worth mentioning that the users will not have local tabs, so they won't see the 'view' and 'edit' tabs provided by the module.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you need, but the bellow code will check if the user has access to the destination and prints the edit link. But better to go with Views' native edit links. Not sure why you can't use them.

```
<?php
$path = "admin/build/views/edit/VIEW-MACHINE-NAME";
$item = menu_get_item($path);
if ( $item['access'] ) {
  print l(t('Edit'), $path);
}
?>
```

replace VIEW-MACHINE-NAME with View's machine name.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  What I'm really trying to get is a parameter from the "views ui basic: edit settings" module.  It allows a user to edit some basic fields with wysiwyg instead of the "scary" views ui.  Before a view can be edited that way, you have check an "allow this view to be editable" box (not exact words).  I'd like to say, "if this view is editable, show this button".

Comment: Forgot to say this, but at this point not using tabs is an exercise for myself.  Originally, the end user had wanted to strip out any controls that weren't obvious - all the views controls and page tabs are out - they just want a single edit button on each page.  It's not how we're going to proceed, but I'm curious about this.  Thanks again.